# Javascript in head doesn't fire

Tags: jquery

I made this site for a friend : http://justindesign.ca/portfolio.php

and the error I get is :

```
Error: $("#slideshow").slides is not a function
Source File: http://justindesign.ca/portfolio.php
Line: 42
```

I HAVE NO IDEA why..... path is good, wp setup is good, firebug doesn't tell me anything is wrong... I am lost... and tired... can you help me find the bug ?... thanks in advance

Comment: We can't see your site, it says it's in "Maintenance Mode." Your error means that jQuery has not been modified with the `slides` plugin. Either it isn't being included properly or it isn't authored properly to be available to jQuery objects (`$.fn.slides` should be how the code for the plugin starts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re-included jQuery after including the plugin.

This replaced the plugged-in jQuery object with a fresh copy.

Comment: Yep !... i did that... stupid me... but from that mistake i learn something... old saying garbage in garbage out !.. .thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I can't see in the source of your page, however, try this:

```
$("#slideshow").slides();
```

when calling a function, you need to add () after the function name

Comment: i have try that SUPER SIMPLE : $(function(){ $('#slideshow').slides(); }); DONT WORK !!!

Comment: do you have a div with id="slideshow"? otherwise this fails.. also, is jquery and the slideshow plugin loaded?